# Timer source code c++

Tags: c++, timer

Hi guys i found a timer source code for c++ 
Found it here:
https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/216933/a-countdown-timer-in-c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int m, s, h;
    cout << "A COUNTDOWN TIMER " << endl;
    cout << "enter time in hours here" << endl;
    cin >> h;
    cout << "enter time in minutes here " << endl;
    cin >> m;
    cout << "enter im in seconds here" << endl;
    cin >> s;
    cout << "Press any key to start" << endl;
    cout << " A COUNTDOWN TIMER" << endl;
    cout << "time remaining" << endl;
    cout << "hours : " << h << "mins : " << m << " secs : " << s << endl;
    for (int hour = h; hour >= 0; hour--)
    {
        for (int min = m; min >= 0; min--)
        {
            if (min == 0 && h > 0)
                m = 59;
            for (int sec = s; sec >= 0; sec--)
            {
                if (sec == 0)
                    s = 59;
                Sleep(1000);
                system("cls");
                cout << hour << " :hours " << min << " :mins " << sec << " :secs" << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "THE END" << endl;

    return 0;
```

The problem i keep getting is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C1075   the left brace '{' was unmatched at the end of the file

I'm not sure where I'm supposed to add a } ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you are missing the `}` after your `return 0;` statement.

Comment: Correct, thanks <3

Comment: *I'm not sure where I'm supposed to add...*  read the error carefully _...the left brace '{' was unmatched **at the end of** the file"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing your end brace at the end of your main function after the return 0;

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark this as the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Cheers.